# Vector I made can't make in c++ a 2-d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I was instructed to make a vector for my CS class. My vector works fine when all I want is a 1-d vector, but if I want something like

```
MyVector<MyVector<Some_Class>> mv;
```

it will work as long as the above code only has one vector stored in it.

```
// this is fine
mv.resize(1);
Some_Class sc_var;
mv[0].push_back(sc_var);
cout << mv[0].size() << endl;
```

but if I do this

```
// this is where the bug is found
mv.resize(2);
Some_class sc_var2;
mv[1].push_back(sc_var2);
cout << mv[0].size() << ' ' << mv[1].size() << endl;
// it will give the output '0 1' when it should give '1 1'
```

I tracked down the bug to this part of my code

```
T *temp_array = new T[cur_size];
for (int i = 0; i < cur_size; i++) {
    temp_array[i] = safe_array[i];
}
```

This part of my code is in the resize method. When debugging I found that temp_array[i] wouldn't be set with the same value of safe_array[i]. which is a problem, because I use temp_array to temporarily store everything from the safe_array so safe_array can be resized to hold more or less elements. So since temp_array[i] isn't being set to safe_array[i], when the value of temp_array is being fed back into safe_array, temp_array[i] is still set to a new MyVector[cur_size].

```
// this is how I got the type of T
cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
// class MyVector<class Some_Class>
```

And that value is fed back into safe_array. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Here's a better example of what I am trying to say

```
Class Cell{
    char data;
    Cell *north = nullptr;
    Cell *east = nullptr;
    Cell *south = nullptr;
    Cell *west = nullptr;
}
MyVector<MyVector<Cell>> mv;
mv.resize(1);
// the below code will work find
mv[0].push_back(9);
cout << mv[0].size() << '\n';
// will print out 1
// below is code that won't work
mv.resize(2);
mv[1].push_back(8);
cout << mv[0].size() << ' ' << mv[1].size() << '\n';
// will print out '0 1', but should print out '1 1'
```

below is my resize method

```
// resizes the array to any size the programmer wants
    void resize(int new_cur_size) {
        int container_size = new_cur_size;

        if (container_size < 10) {
            container_size = 10;
        }

        if (new_cur_size <= 0) {
            SafeArrayException ex;
            throw ex;
            return;
        }
        // creates a new dynamic array the same size and type
        // as the underlying array so the underlying array can
        // be copied, resized, and refilled
        T *temp_array = new T[cur_size];

        // copies everything from underlying array to temp array
        for (int i = 0; i < cur_size; i++) {
            // this part is the problem
            // temp_array[i] will not be set to
            // safe_array[i] (when mv.resize() is called
            // not when something like mv[0].resize() is executed
            temp_array[i] = safe_array[i];
        }

        // resizes the array
        delete[] safe_array;
        safe_array = new T[container_size];

        // fills the underlying array back up with its old elements
        // in the same position they where at before resizing
        for (int i = 0; i < new_cur_size; i++) {
            if (cur_size > 0 && i <= cur_size - 1) {
                safe_array[i] = temp_array[i];
            }
        }

        // lets template know that the array has a new compacity
        // and frees up memory used by temp array

        container_cur_size = container_size;

        cur_size = new_cur_size;

        delete[] temp_array;
    }
```

Comment: *My vector works fine when all I want is a 1-d vector* -- Obviously you didn't properly *unit test* your vector class thoroughly.  You can't make vectors of vectors if the simple tests don't work properly.  Second, what is `Some_class`?  And it would be helpful if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in your copy-constructor or move-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0 1" should be the expected output. the vector at mv[0] is an empty vector because you have not added (pushed back) an element to it. If you do a push_back on that vector, its size will become 1 as well: Example

```
mv.resize(2);
Some_class sc_var2;
mv[0].push_back(sc_var2); //mv[0] wont be empty once this line has run
mv[1].push_back(sc_var2);
cout << mv[0].size() << ' ' << mv[1].size() << endl; //"1 1"
```